# Does anyone know how sites are generating the Apple App Store updated apps feeds?

Tags: iphone, rss, app-store

A lot of sites have rss feeds for updated and new apps on the Apple iPhone App Store. However, Apple's rss feed generator only shows feeds for the top 100 free/paid apps. So how can I generate my own database of new/updated apps in the same fashion as all these folks are? What magic feed are they accessing?

Comment: It appears one can read the itunes store pages as xml.

http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/[url]

from

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGenre?id=6016&mt=8

just replace the 'itunes.apple.com' with 'ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net'

Comment: Post this as an answer to your own question and accept it. That way, the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple have an [RSS generator for iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/).

> Provide the information requested
>   below, then click Generate to view the
>   feed URL. These feeds automatically
>   update to reflect iTunes' top charts
>   and new content, so you'll always be
>   up to date with the latest in the
>   iTunes Store.

e.g. Top 10 apps is `http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/sf=143441/limit=10/xml`

Comment: There does not seem to be an option to get updated apps. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like "new apps" is the only option. Not clear if that includes updates or not.

Answer (score -1):

This looks nice: http://appstorefeeds.com/.

It is a complete collection of feeds.