# Retrieval of AppStore charts via API?

Tags: charts, app-store, itunes

I'm looking to query the iTunes appstore charts to determine what position a given app holds.

This would need to go as deep as possible with a view to tracking an apps movement from launch to appearing in the top 100 and further.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

You can get the top 200 apps, podcasts, etc. from the iTunes RSS feeds:

http://itunes.apple.com/rss

edit: The iTunes RSS feeds now limit you to the top 200. Up until a week ago it would return the top 400

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of sites out there that do this, but they all operate via some flavor of screen scraping. Apple has no API for this, and I doubt they ever will.

Answer (score 0):

The app store data is in XML format. You can use any number of parsers — click on the search field in the top-right corner of the Stack Overflow page and type "iphone xml parse", for example, for questions about how to parse XML on an iPhone.

Comment: How does one retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0):

Apple will likely reject your application if you use it to scrape the Apple sites directly as it violates their Terms and User Agreement.  If you want to do an app like this, I suggest setting up your own service that scrapes Apple, then use the iPhone app to connect to your own servers.

As mentioned below there are plenty of good ways to grab the data.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989858/retrieving-itunes-app-store-xml-with-curl-and-php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740310/does-anyone-know-how-sites-are-generating-the-apple-app-store-updated-apps-feeds)

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in checking whether an app is being featured on the App Store homepage a category homepage, in What's new, What's hot or Staff picks, you might wanna have a look at a script I wrote:

http://www.futuretap.com/blog/scraping-app-store-featured-entries/

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the top fifty songs:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=50/json